# After curl compiles lib successfully, an error is reported when using

Tags: c++, curl, cmake, clion

Use the clion cmake file as follows:

```
set_target_properties(libcurl PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/curl/libcurl-d.lib)
set_target_properties(untitled4 PROPERTIES COMPILE_OPTIONS "/MTd")
target_link_libraries(untitled4 ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/curl/WS2_32.Lib ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/curl/Wldap32.Lib libcurl);
```

An error occurs when running a specific curl request:

```
libcurl-d.lib(strerror.obj) : error LNK2019: Unresolved external symbol __imp___sys_errlist, which is referenced in function Curl_strerror
libcurl-d.lib(strerror.obj) : error LNK2019: Unresolved external symbol __imp___sys_nerr, referenced in function Curl_strerror
libcurl-d.lib(cookie.obj): error LNK2019: Unresolved external symbol __imp_fputs, referenced in function cookie_output
libcurl-d.lib(altsvc.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_fputs
libcurl-d.lib(hsts.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_fputs
OLDNAMES.lib(unlink.obi) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_unlink
libcurl-d.lib(cookie.obj): error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_unlink
libcurl-d.lib(altsvc.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_unlink
libcurl-d.lib(hsts.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_unlink
libcurl-d.lib(fopen.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_unlink
libcurl-d.lib(http.obj): error LNK2019: Unresolved external symbol __imp__time64, which is referenced in function Curl_buffer_send
libcurl-d.lib(tftp.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__time64
libcurl-d.lib(http_aws_sigv4.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__time64
libcurl-d.lib(curl_ntlm_core.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__time64
libcurl-d.lib(cookie.obj): error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__time64
libcurl-d.lib(altsvc.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__time64
libcurl-d.lib(hsts.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__time64
libcurl-d.lib(hostip.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__time64
libcurl-d.lib(mime.obj) : error LNK2019: Unresolved external symbol __imp_feof, referenced in function read_part_content
libcurl-d.lib(curl_get_line.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_feof
libcurl-d.lib(warnless.obj): error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_read, referenced in function curlx_read
OLDNAMES.lib(read.obi) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_read
libcurl-d.lib(warnless.obj) : error LNK2019: Unresolved external symbol __imp_write, which is referenced in function curlx_write
OLDNAMES.lib(write.obi) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_write
libcurl-d.lib(system_win32.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__mbspbrk, referenced in function _tcspbrk
libcurl-d.lib(altsvc.obj) : error LNK2019: Unresolved external symbol __imp_strspn, referenced in function Curl_altsvc_parse
libcurl-d.lib(urlapi.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_strspn
libcurl-d.lib(altsvc.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp___stdio_common_vsscanf, referenced in function _vsscanf_l
libcurl-d.lib(hsts.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___stdio_common_vsscanf
libcurl-d.lib(http_aws_sigv4.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___stdio_common_vsscanf
libcurl-d.lib(curl_multibyte.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_fopen, referenced in function curlx_win32_fopen
libcurl-d.lib(curl_multibyte.obj) : error LNK2019: Unresolved external symbol __imp__access, which is referenced in function curlx_win32_access
libcurl-d.lib(curl_multibyte.obj) : error LNK2019: Unresolved external symbol __imp__open, which is referenced in function curlx_win32_open
libcurl-d.lib(curl_multibyte.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__stat64, referenced in function curlx_win32_stat
libcurl-d.lib(curl_get_line.obj) : error LNK2019: Unresolved external symbol __imp_fgets, referenced in function Curl_get_line
libcurl-d.lib(parsedate.obj) : error LNK2019: Unresolved external symbol __imp__gmtime64, which is referenced in function gmtime
libcurl-d.lib(fopen.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_fdopen, which is referenced in function Curl_fopen
OLDNAMES.lib(fdopen.obi) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_fdopen
libcurl-d.lib(fopen.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_fileno, referenced in function Curl_fopen
OLDNAMES.lib(fileno.obi) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_fileno
libcurl-d.lib(fopen.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_close, which is referenced in function Curl_fopen
libcurl-d.lib(file.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_close
OLDNAMES.lib(close.obi) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_close
libcurl-d.lib(fopen.obj) : error LNK2019: Unresolved external symbol __imp__fstat64, which is referenced in function Curl_fopen
libcurl-d.lib(file.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__fstat64
libcurl-d.lib(curl_threads.obj) : error LNK2019: Unresolved external symbol __imp__beginthreadex, referenced in function Curl_thread_create
OLDNAMES.lib(unlink.obi) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__unlink
OLDNAMES.lib(fdopen.obi) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__fdopen
```

I have tried to introduce static libraries such as WS2_32.Lib and Wldap32.Lib mentioned on the Internet, but it still has not been solved. I don’t even know the cause of this problem.

Comment: Did you build and tried linking to a static libcurl?

Comment: link to static library, but it didn't work

Comment: You need to define `CURL_STATICLIB` if you're linking to a static libcurl. Use `target_compile_definition()` or `#define`.

Comment: I added these three lines of code when I was querying the information.
`add_definitions(-DBUILDING_LIBCURL)
add_definitions(-DHTTP_ONLY)
add_definitions(-DCURL_STATICLIB)`

It seems like this is what you were talking about